# повторить строку N раз на bash

Tags: linux, bash, список

Подскажите как повторить каждую строку текстового документа нужное кол-во раз. Есть какая-нибудь простая и изящная команда на bash ? Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

некоторые из [множества вариантов](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81904/110559), правда, использующие другие программы:

```
$ sed 'p;p' файл
$ perl -lpE 'say;say' файл
$ awk '1;1;1' файл
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++)print}' файл
```

а средствами программы *bash* не так изящно:

```
$ while read line; do for i in {1..3}; do echo "$line"; done; done < файл
```

---

каждый из приведённых примеров выведет утроенной каждую строку файла.

Comment: Хорошо, а если много повторений, на sed или awk нельзя ли как-то синтаксис изменить, чтобы указывать N раз, а не каждый повтор через `;` ?

Comment: посмотрите ответы по ссылке. там наверняка есть и что-то вроде `$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) print}' файл`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Может заодно и подскажете, как сделать и повтор каждой строки N раз но не отдельными строками, а вывод вместе в одной строке, то есть, если строка `123` , то вывод N раз подряд (здесь три раза) `123123123` . `awk '{print $1 $1 $1}'` или `awk '{print $0$0$0}'` - как правильнее ? более короткий синтаксис есть?

Answer (score 2):

```
n=5 # изменить на нужное к-во
# cat file.txt | while read string; do
while read string; do
    for i in $(seq 1 $n); do 
       printf '%s\n' "$string" # здесь не обязательно printf '%s\n' достаточно echo
    done
done  < file.txt # поправил в соответствии с конструктивной критикой
```

ну или чтобы изящно

`quantity=5 # Изменить на нужное количество
awk '{for(i=1;i<=count;i++)print}' count=$quantity file.txt`

Comment: Yet another *Useless use of cat*...